# condition between on events using nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have few on events and I need to put if condition in between them so if condition is not met the code will not continue the the next events.
for example if current price> 50 do not continue to the next on. example:

```
}).on('tickPrice', function (tickerId, tickType, price, canAutoExecute) {
  currentPrice = price
  tickType=tickType
  console.log(
    '%s %s%d %s%d %s%s',
    chalk.cyan(util.format('[%s]', ib.util.tickTypeToString(tickType))),
    chalk.bold('tickerId='), tickerId,
  );
}).on('nextValidId', function (orderId) {
  console.log(
    '%s %s%d',
  );
```

Comment: You can't really do what you're asking.  Event handlers are installed ahead of time long before the actual events occur.  So, as soon as you initialize your code, both the `tickPrice` and the `nextvalidId` event handlers are already installed.  What you probably want to do instead is to set some state somewhere on a particular object if the price is above some threshold and then future event handlers on this particular object can check that state and modify their behavior.  To help you in more detail, we'd have to see much more of the relevant code.

Comment: thanks for your comment. here is an example of the full code. https://github.com/pilwon/node-ib/blob/master/examples/placeOrder.js

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap this call in to a promise and reject/resolve as soon as your condition is met. The function caller can then await the promise returned and continue your program

```
   function streamer() {
         return new Primise((resolve, reject) => {
          ....// your initial code here 

   }).on('tickPrice', function (tickerId, tickType, price, canAutoExecute) {
     currentPrice = price
     tickType=tickType
     console.log(
'%s %s%d %s%d %s%s',
         chalk.cyan(util.format('[%s]', ib.util.tickTypeToString(tickType))),
         chalk.bold('tickerId='), tickerId,
     );


     if(price > 50) {
        return resolve();
     }

    }).on('nextValidId', function (orderId) {
        console.log('%.s %s%d',
        );

    ...// rest of your code 
    
    return resolve()
   });
}
```

The above example will resolve only then price is 50 inside the tickPrice event, and continue to wait for events other wise

I added a resolve at end of next valid id as an example. In your code you would probs have an end event for which you would add the last resolve